# How much is a sachet of gelatin in teaspoons or tablespoons?

Tags: measurements, gelatin

I am following a muffin recipe which calls for 2 sachets of gelatin. How much is a sachet of gelatin in teaspoons or tablespoons?

Comment: Gelatin in muffins? Unusual. You wouldn’t have the recipe for us to understand better, how the recipe is built?

Comment: Also, what is the size of a sachet?

Comment: @JulianaKarasawaSouza - I believe that is the original question!

Comment: Does the recipe (or accompanying materials) mention a brand name of gelatin? A sachet is just a "small packet" if there is a reference to a specific brand of gelatin, you might just be able to use two packets, etc.

Comment: @GregNickoloff I mean in grams / ounces

Comment: @JulianaKarasawaSouza I think OP would also be happy to know that. Sounds like the (bad) recipe says literally just 'sachets'. Even worse than 'tin', at least that's *almost* entirely standard (volume), across products even. (And where it deviates, that tends to be the norm for that product.)

Comment: Would be nice to see the original recipe... might not help with the "sachet" problem, but I can't really wrap my mind around gelatin in a muffin recipe. Any chance of posting that?

Answer (score 5):

Knox gelatin is 4 packets in a 1oz box, so 1/4oz per packet.

The Great Lakes canister of gelatin that I have says that a serving is "1 tbsp. (1/4oz, 7g)"

So I'd assume 1TB (roughly 15mL for those not in the US) per packet ... but I have no idea if this is like salt, where they don't all pack to the same density.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to weigh .5 oz for accuracy. I get my gelatin in bulk and tried a measuring cup and tbsp and it wasnt very consistent compared to using a scale